# Getting GWT Canvas to work on Eclipse in Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, html, gwt, ubuntu-10.04

Ok, for this i faced a number of hurdles. But I got it working. 
I'm just wondering if there was an easier way... Otherwise this is what worked for me.

I will stick with my solution, but if you have a better one like "I just upgraded x to y" it would be good to know.

I have/had

Ubuntu 10.04 (LTS) 
Eclipse 2.5 Galileo (from the repository - and needed for other projects)
Google suite plugin 2.4.2
gwt 2.0.3

If you want to use some fancy HTML5 stuff like canvas, gwt 2.0.3 wont cut it.

As far as i could tell, a basic upgrade of any of these using the methods listed on the respective pages - just lead to headaches. 
It seems like newer versions of GWT require newer versions of Eclipse
The basic cause is that Ubuntu wont let you upgrade eclipse using the eclipse methods.

The short fast answer was to install another eclipse from tarball and go from there. I started it on a new workspace as well. 
I dont know if two versions of eclipse can handle the same workspace.

I suppose upgrading Ubuntu to 11+ would probably do the same thing. but I'm quite happy to be on an LTS release.

Answer (score 1):

You  don't need to upgrade plugin in order to change version of GWT you are using. I haven't personally tried GPE 2.4.2 with GWT 2.4 but most of the time when I needed a different GWT version, I just downloaded GWT SDK and then pointed eclipse to use this SDK (you can manage GWT SDK's in Preferences/Google/Web Toolkit). As usual you can set each project to use different SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I switch between vista, win 7, ubuntu 10LTS and 11.10 when programming for GWT on GPE.

The reason I am not having problems is I use Springsource Tool Suite (STS), Springsource packaging of Eclipse. I used to use Yoxos but I found Springsource does a much better job. A better job in the sense that STS package of Eclipse gives me the plugins that I want and their dashboard/update sites makes sure my plug-ins work well together. Also yoxos keeps changing the layout and flow of their web site confusing me.

In the past, using yoxos to package my eclipse was a headache, as I had to be a guru of various versions of plugins.

Recently, I had problems with maven not working with a latest snapshot of Indigo. The answer was right on the STS web site. Not only giving the answer but the packaging to replace the version of m2e that would work.

I did use synaptic/software centre to install indigo on my ubuntu 11.10 machine, but I never use it - I have no idea why I even felt compelled to install it. Because I finally had to install STS.

OK, STS offers me some computer games to play around with when I am bored, like - aspectj, spring roo, groovy.

IMO, STS is to EClipse as Ubuntu is to Linux. Anyway, I have to depend on the consistency of STS because of my having to switch between windows and linux.

I wish to advise people to not use vanilla eclipse (like installing eclipse using ubuntu synaptics) because I have witnessed programmers encountering plugin version conflicts trying to update or install plugins - unless you work in a large org with a person chartered to package eclipse. Otherwise, it is really a waste of company time and money if we waste a week of our time per year untangling eclipse issues - and multiply that by the number of programmers.

I think, on the one hand eclipse has a very cohesive vision, but on the other has a rather anarchic execution which then enables the fluorishing existence of MyEclipse and SpringSource.

I know that "Eclipse experts" would disagree with me. But the fact that they needed to be experts in Eclipse and I simply want to be just a programmer speaks volumes why they would disagree with me.